# I keep getting "index out of range in self" during forward pass

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I am fine tuning a Longformer Encoder Decoder model for multi document text summarization. When I try to run through the forward pass, it gives me an error "index out of range in self". The input shape seems to be correct, but the debugger points to something in torch Embedding going wrong. How do I fix this?

```
num_epochs = 8
num_training_steps = num_epochs * len(train_dataloader)
optimizer = Adam(MODEL.parameters(), lr=3e-5)
lr_scheduler = get_scheduler(
    name="linear", optimizer=optimizer, num_warmup_steps=1, num_training_steps=num_training_steps # CHANGE LATER!!!!!!!
)
progress_bar = tqdm(range(num_training_steps))

# Training mode
MODEL.train()

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
  for batch_idx, batch in enumerate(train_dataloader):

    # Encode data
    input_ids_all = []
    for cluster in batch["document"]:
      articles = cluster.split("|||||")[:-1]
      for i, article in enumerate(articles):
        article = article.replace("\n", " ")
        article = " ".join(article.split())
        articles[i] = article
      input_ids = []
      for article in articles:
        input_ids.extend(TOKENIZER.encode(article, truncation=True, max_length=4096 // len(articles))[1:-1])
        input_ids.append(DOCSEP_TOKEN_ID)
      input_ids = ([TOKENIZER.bos_token_id]+input_ids+[TOKENIZER.eos_token_id])
      input_ids_all.append(torch.tensor(input_ids))
      input_ids = torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence(input_ids_all, batch_first=True, padding_value=PAD_TOKEN_ID)

    # Forward pass
    global_attention_mask = torch.zeros_like(input_ids)
    global_attention_mask[:, 0] = 1
    global_attention_mask[input_ids == DOCSEP_TOKEN_ID] = 1

    print(input_ids.shape)
    # outputs = MODEL.forward(input_ids) # <---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- causing a bug
    outputs = MODEL.forward(input_ids=input_ids_all, global_attention_mask=global_attention_mask)

    # Backprop
    loss = outputs.loss
    loss.backward()

    # GD
    optimizer.step()
    lr_scheduler.step()
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    progress_bar.update(1)

    # Decode output
    generated_str = TOKENIZER.batch_decode(generated_ids.tolist(), skip_special_tokens=True)
    metric.add_batch(predictions=generated_str, references=batch["summary"])

    # Calculate metrics
    print(f"Epoch: {epoch+1}, Batch: {batch_idx+1}:")
    print(metric.compute())
```

Comment: Please provide the full code with imports so it is reproducable, also information about the input data, where exactly the error is and the error trace.